# Kindle screen suddenly became very dim on LG tablet running 4.2.2 Can't increase brightness

Tags: applications, screen, screen-brightness, amazon-kindle

How can I increase brightness of Kindle screen on my LG tablet running 4.2.2? Screen suddenly became very dim. Thanks.

Comment: Did you just upgrade the Kindle app? You can manage brightness at two levels - the device, and within the app. On the Device - click Settings>Display>Brightness. Maybe you have it on Auto Brightness? Turn that off and select brightness to taste. Option 2: Within the app - while reading a book, the font settings also controls brightness. Maybe you have the app on Auto Brightness? Turn that off and select brightness to taste.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a much easier solution,  especially if the screen is so dim that you can't read any of the display options. Simply place TWO fingers on the screen and slide them up for brighter, down for dimmer. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the Kindle App, the App 'overwrites' the system brightness. You have to change the brightness within the Kindle app by tapping on the "Aa"-button in the action bar (the menu where you can set font size etc.). There is a slider where you can set the brightness while reading.